# Polars: create an integer column from another one by computing the difference with the largest smaller value from a list

Tags: python, list, python-polars

I have a `polars` dataframe like this one:

```
shape: (10, 2)
┌────────┬───────┐
│ foo    ┆ bar   │
│ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═══════╡
│ 86     ┆ 11592 │
│ 109    ┆ 2765  │
│ 109    ┆ 4228  │
│ 153    ┆ 4214  │
│ 153    ┆ 7217  │
│ 153    ┆ 11095 │
│ 160    ┆ 1134  │
│ 222    ┆ 5509  │
│ 225    ┆ 10150 │
│ 239    ┆ 4151  │
└────────┴───────┘
```

And a **sorted** list of integers `points`:

```
points = [0, 1500, 3000, 4500, 6000, 7500, 9000, 10500, 12000]
```

I want to create a new column `baz`, such that for each element `y` of `bar`, I find the largest `x` in `points` such that `x =< y`. Then the element of `baz` is `y - x`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a solution which fully relies on polars expressions, by using  [`join_asof`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html). First, create DataFrame out of the list and then join (I'm assuming that `points` list is pre-sorted)

Here, we leave `strategy` argument of the join empty, so default `backward` strategy is going to be used.

> A `backward` search selects the last row in the right DataFrame **(in our case - list of points)** whose `on` key is less than or equal to the left’s key:

```py
df_points = pl.DataFrame({'point': points})

(
    df.sort('bar')
    .join_asof(df_points.set_sorted('point'), right_on='point', left_on='bar')
    .with_columns(baz=pl.col('bar') - pl.col('point'))
    .drop('point')
    .sort('foo')
)

┌─────┬───────┬──────┐
│ foo ┆ bar   ┆ baz  │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 86  ┆ 11592 ┆ 1092 │
│ 109 ┆ 2765  ┆ 1265 │
│ 109 ┆ 4228  ┆ 1228 │
│ 153 ┆ 4214  ┆ 1214 │
│ 153 ┆ 7217  ┆ 1217 │
│ 153 ┆ 11095 ┆ 595  │
│ 160 ┆ 1134  ┆ 1134 │
│ 222 ┆ 5509  ┆ 1009 │
│ 225 ┆ 10150 ┆ 1150 │
│ 239 ┆ 4151  ┆ 1151 │
└─────┴───────┴──────┘
```

Comment: I didn't think of `pl.DataFrame.join_asof`. That's definitely the preferred approach @DeltaIV.

Comment: yes, indeed `points` is sorted in ascending order. I already edited my question to make this clear